NextJS - ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined
I am using App Router.
app/layout.tsx
import PushNotificationLayout from "./pushNotificationLayout";
...
return (
  <PushNotificationLayout />
)


app/PushNotificationLayout.tsx
"use client";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/messaging";
import { firebaseCloudMessaging } from "../../utils/firebase";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

function PushNotificationLayout({ children }) {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken();
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        // Do something
      });
    }

    async function setToken() {
      try {
        const token = await firebaseCloudMessaging.init();
        ...
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  }, []);

  function getMessage() {
    firebase.messaging().onMessage(
      (message) => {
       ...
      },
      (e) => {...}
    );
  }

  return (...);
}

// I tried to disable ssr but not working
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(PushNotificationLayout), {
  ssr: false,
});


/utils/firebase.js
import "firebase/messaging";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import localforage from "localforage";

const firebaseCloudMessaging = {
  init: async () => {
    localforage.removeItem("fcm_token");

    if (!firebase?.apps?.length) {
      firebase?.initializeApp({...});

      try {
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();

        const tokenInLocalForage = await localforage.getItem("fcm_token");
        if (tokenInLocalForage !== null) {
          return tokenInLocalForage;
        }

        const status = await Notification.requestPermission();
        if (status && status === "granted") {
          const fcm_token = await messaging.getToken(...);

          if (fcm_token) {
            localforage.setItem("fcm_token", fcm_token);
            return fcm_token;
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {...}
    }
  },
};
export { firebaseCloudMessaging };


I thought it might be related to localforage, which uses indexDB internally because of the error message ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined.
Therefore I tried to disable ssr by
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(PushNotificationLayout), {
  ssr: false,
});

But it still renders in the server, because I saw the same error in the server side instead of client side.
I also tried to comment out <PushNotificationLayout /> in layout.tsx, and the error is gone
